# React-Native-Tts only changing voices but not language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I'm making an app in react native, and using the react-native-tts package for speech synthesis. I want the user to have a language option from among the languages that are already installed in the phone. I have a language selection screen from where I am feeding data into the AsyncStorage, and a screen that uses tts. This screen fetches data from the Async Storage and uses that language for speech synthesis. However, when I select a language from my selection screen, the Tts language only changes if the language is English (for example en-In or en-US).

Here is the code used in the language selection screen

```
changeLanguage = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('LanguageId', this.state.selectedLanguage.id); // The voice Id
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('Language', this.state.selectedLanguage.code); // The language code, 'en-IN' or 'en-US'
}
```

And here is the code for the screen that uses Tts

```
async onReceiveFocus() {
    const languageCode = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Language');

    this.setState({
        languageCode: languageCode
    }); // Setting the state for other uses

    Tts.setDefaultLanguage(languageCode);
}
```

Comment: Solved: I just had to uninstall the voice data for languages and install it again, and it started working. I have no idea why something like this was happening though.